# Get databind value of selected template field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I would like my website to allow users to download files which are stored as blobs on the database, the database holds fileID fileName and theFile. I have a grid view with two columns, fileName and a template column, which is databound to fileID and has a linkbutton. When the link is clicked it calls to a function which downloads the file. 
The function needs the fileID to download the file, how do I get the fileID bound to the selected linkbutton.

am using vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databind the `CommandArgument` of the `LinkButton` to the id of the file